# OpenCV findContours: effects and use of the CV_RETR_FLOODFILL flag

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0

I am wondering about the use of the retrieval mode CV_RETR_FLOODFILL in combination with opencv's findContours function. I am familiar with the floodfill algorithm in general.

The documentation only states that "the input can also be a 32-bit integer image of labels".
https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0

The RetrievalModes documentation does not state anything at all.
https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga819779b9857cc2f8601e6526a3a5bc71

I am particularly interested in the differences to other approaches when retrieving only the outermost contours in a binary image (e.g. CV_RETR_EXTERNAL or some hierarchy/ size based filtering), but any information would be helpful.